# NSIS: LangString X set multiple times for 0, wasting space

Tags: nsis

I want to define `LangString` for more languages. Here is a example

```
LangString TEXT_LICENSE_TITLE ${ENGLISH_LANG} "Installer"
LangString TEXT_LICENSE_TITLE ${NORWEGIAN_LANG} "installatør"
```

But I got the warning `LangString "TEXT_LICENSE_TITLE" set multiple times for 0, wasting space`.

I think I have the correct order. Here my code

```
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Norwegian"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
```

then

```
LangString TEXT_LICENSE_TITLE ${ENGLISH_LANG} "Installer"
LangString TEXT_LICENSE_TITLE ${NORWEGIAN_LANG} "installatør"

!define MUI_TEXT_LICENSE_TITLE $(TEXT_LICENSE_TITLE)
```

So how could i get away this warning? I use `nsis 2.51`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0` is the default/"last used" language id and it is used because you did not pass a valid id.

The correct syntax is

```
LangString TEXT_LICENSE_TITLE ${LANG_ENGLISH} "English text"
```

Note the use of `{ }` braces, not `( )` for the 2nd parameter. `${}` expands a define at compile-time (what you need in this case) and the other expands a langstring. The name of the define is `LANG_*` if I remember correctly.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I changed it, but still get the same warning.

Comment: `LANG_*`, not `*_LANG`.

Comment: Good catch. Thank you very much.